# Partition mounted on boot, but not listed not in fstab

Tags: linux, fedora, boot, mount

I thought I was a fairly advanced Linux administrator working on a Centos (Fedora) machine.  I have modified fstab to not mount a particular partition at boot, yet it keeps mounting.  It is no longer in fstab, but I can see it mounted in mtab (last line) on reboot.  It is immediately mounted, as soon as I login.  Any idea at what point during a reboot this partition could be mounting?  I didn't see anything in cron, but not certain.  any ideas on where to look for clues would be great.  Thanks in advance.

`/etc/fstab`:

```
LABEL=/                 /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
LABEL=SWAP-sda2         swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

`/etc/mtab`:

```
/dev/sda3 / ext3 rw 0 0
proc /proc proc rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
/dev/sda1 /boot ext3 rw 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw 0 0
none /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw 0 0
sunrpc /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs rpc_pipefs rw 0 0
none /var/lib/xenstored tmpfs rw 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /home/jason/images ext3 rw 0 0
```

EDIT: I did turn off autofs (according to solution provided) in chkconfig and reboot, but the directory was still mounted. Aside from fstab what are the possible ways to mount a drive/folder during or immediately after boot?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a server, eventually figured out someone had placed a mount command at startup in root's crontab.

Hope I save someone else the time it took me to find this...

Comment: Thank you, this indeed helped me found it too in `sudo crontab -e`

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible that it's being mounted by the automounter. Try disabling the autofs service (`sudo chkconfig autofs off`) and rebooting - if it doesn't mount with autofs turned off, have a like at /etc/auto.master (and friends).

More info on autofs configuration can be found in RedHat's manual: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s2-nfs-config-autofs.html

Comment: My apologies, the server in question is in production and difficult to "try new stuff."  I did finally get a chance to turn off autofs in chkconfig and reboot, but the folder was still mounted. Aside from fstab what are the possible ways to mount a drive/folder during or immediately after boot?